# Dereferencing a pointer that has been assigned specific memory address

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working with pointers and arrays where I have to specify where does the array starts in memory or what memory address the pointer should hold. The pointer or array takes the address; however, I cannot deference or assign a value.

I tried to run following code but it gives me Segmentation Fault. What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

```
int *a = (int *)0x100;
cout << a << endl;            //prints out 0x100
*(a) = 10;        <------ seg fault on this line
```

following the code for array,

```
int *b = new b[10];
b = (int *)0x0;
cout << b << endl;           //prints out 0x0
b[0] = 10;     <----  seg fault on this line
```

Comment: The thing you're doing wrong is trying to access a memory address that is not allocated...

Comment: You can't just set a pointer to any random value and expect to be able to dereference it. You must set it to a *valid memory address*. It's not clear what you are really trying to do so can't suggest the right way to do it. And please pick only one language. C and C++ are different languages and any answer may be different depending on which language you are really interested in (looks like it's C++).

Comment: Is this code that runs on an embedded system?  It might work, depending if 0x100 is a valid address and contains memory there.

Comment: What I am trying to do is start an array at specific memory address because I have another program who is trying to assume and start accessing the elements from that specified address. I am not even sure if 0x100 is open to programmer or protected by the OS.

Comment: @E.Mike If you have no reason to think that address is valid *why are you using it*? This seems like an XY problem. Ask about what you're actually trying to do, not how you think you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are dereferencing a pointer that does not point to an object. That has undefined behaviour, but if you are in luck, the OS may detect the mistake and raise a seg fault.

Solution: First allocate memory for an object. How you should allocate, depends on how you intend to use the object. A simple way to allocate an object is to use an automatic variable:

```
int main() {
    int object;
    int* pointer = &object; // now you can assign the pointer to the specific memory address of the existing object
    *pointer     = 10;      // dereferencing is OK
}


flag
```

> wouldn't pointer takes address of object which is not specified?

The pointer would take the address of the specified object. The compiler specifies what the address will be.

> How can I make pointer point to address 0x100 ...

Using a cast. Your program already does that.

> ... and use that memory for my purpose?

Using arbitrary memory not possible in standard C++. You will need to resort to platform specific ways to deal with your problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write. Simple and correct answer.

Comment: wouldn't pointer takes address of object which is not specified? How can I make pointer point to address 0x100 and use that memory for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

allocate memory first for int a, you are segfaulting because of that.

```
int *a = new int;
*a = 10;
delete a;
```

for you second case you are also dereferencing a null pointer. you dont need to set b to address zero. by doing so i believe you lose your array.